# A confusing 2-component spinor notation

Tags: field-theory, notation, spinors

In Michael Dine's *Supersymmetry and String Theory*, the Lagrangian for QCD of one single quark is written as (in equation (5.1))

$$ \mathcal{L} = -\frac{1}{4g^2} F^2 + i\bar{q} D^\mu \sigma_\mu \bar{q}^* + i{q} D^\mu \sigma_\mu {q}^* + m\bar{q}q + m^* \bar{q}^* q^* $$

Dine didn't explain his 2-component spinor notation here. Does anyone know of this notation?

Comment: Are these the same 2-component spinors that are present in the Dirac equation? If so, then they're the spinors of the quark and antiquark fields.

Comment: @probably_someone Is $q$ transforming in the (1/2,0) rep and $\bar{q}$ in (0,1/2)?